# string replaceAll() is not working

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to get the desired content from an incoming string from sever. I have used below code but it is not working.

```
ServerResponse = response.toString();
ServerResponse = ServerResponse.replaceAll("[\\d]", "");
list =ServerResponse.split("\n");
```

but this is not working and I am getting the list as

```
[1234] apple
[1122] Linux
[3344] window
```

I want to get only

```
apple
Linux
windows
```

Comment: What do you the regex - `[\\d]` mean? What will it match?

Comment: you may split again a space... like `for(String line: list) System.out.println(line.split(" ")[1]`;

Comment: Balaji's answer seems to work and it's on the same track as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try next regEx  `\\[\\d*\\]`, it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ServerResponse = ServerResponse.replaceAll("\\[\\d*\\]", "");
list =ServerResponse.split("\n");
```

it will works.

Comment: why it is downvoted? the fellow who downvoted it, should give the proper reason...

Comment: +1. You earned 8 reputation because the guy didn't feel like giving a reason. Although, you should explain your code in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
String[] temp = serverResponse.split("[");
for(String str : temp){
    list.add(str.substring(4));
}
```

And finally, you have the list you want.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 ServerResponse = response.toString();
 ServerResponse = ServerResponse.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", ""); 
 list =ServerResponse.split("\n");
```

Comment: its not working? I had checked it.Be sure your input is what you written here in your question?